# Error with hybrid angular1+2 application: Uncaught Error: UpgradeAdapter cannot be instantiated without an NgModule of the Angular 2 app

Tags: angularjs, angular2-upgrade

I am starting an angular2 project with the hope of reusing my angular1 components. I tried to setup my project based on this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/yMjghOFhFWuY8G1fVIEg but when I tried to run my app, I got this error:

```
  Uncaught Error: UpgradeAdapter cannot be instantiated without an NgModule of the Angular 2 app.
```

The plunkr just instantiated the upgrade adapter without any ng2 module and I don't understand why it didn't work for me. I am not sure what the version of angular2 the plunkr is using but I am using version 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently angular 2.0.0 requires a NgModule to be passed to the UpgradeAdapter constructor. I digged out the following code snippet from @angular/update that works:

```
var adapter = new UpgradeAdapter(forwardRef(() => MyNg2Module));
var module = angular.module('myExample', []);

module.directive('greet', function () {
 return {
 scope: {salutation: '=', name: '='},
 template: '{{salutation}} {{name}}! - <span ng-transclude></span>'
};
});

module.directive('ng2', adapter.downgradeNg2Component(Ng2));

@Component({
  selector: 'ng2',
  template: 'ng2 template: <greet salutation="Hello" [name]="world">text</greet>'
})
class Ng2 {
}

@NgModule({
 declarations: [Ng2, adapter.upgradeNg1Component('greet')],
 imports: [BrowserModule]
})
class MyNg2Module {
}

document.body.innerHTML = '<ng2></ng2>';

adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['myExample']).ready(function () {
  expect(document.body.textContent).toEqual("ng2 template: Hello world! - text");
});
```

Comment: Not sure if you had this elsewhere in your code but you also need `import { forwardRef } from '@angular/core';`